# Can't get my QT Designer UI to run from script

Tags: python, qt

Ok I hope I can make this understandable...
So I created an UI in QT designer - named heatwindow.ui
Next I wrote this following script in a file named heatwindow.py:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtUiTools
from HeatModel import *
from vsmutils import *

class HeatWindow:
"""Main window class for the Flow application"""

    def __init__(self, app):
        """Class constructor"""
        # Assign our application instance as a member variable
        self.app = app
        # Create an instance of our HeatModel class
        #self.heatModel = HeatModel()
        # Load and show our user interface
        self.ui = loadUiWidget('heatwindow.ui') 
        self.ui.show() 
        self.ui.raise_()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = appInstance()
    app.Create()
    HeatWindow(app)
    window = HeatWindow(app)
    app.Run()
```

Ok, so vsmutils is a script that we got from our teacher...
Anyways - my problem is that nothing happens when running the script. Actually it seems the process in Python gets killed entirely, I have to press "Run again this program" (Spyder) in the Console. When debugging it seems this happens after the line

```
window = HeatWindow(app)
```

I hope this is enough info to help me, if not please tell what I should add!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it finally.
So I am going to post how I did it for others to see if they had the same problem... Cause this was just frustrating.

So- I use Windows 7, Python 2.7.6, Spyder... The script crashed all the time when using QT/Pyside. The solution was to delete a file qt.conf that is inside a Python 2.7.6 folder... And now it works... Don't know why though, but it took me 16 hours to find out.